# C# Generics - Constraints on type parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to build a factory method that uses the generics feature of C#.

In this factory method I would like to constraint it to some specific classes, all of which do not have a default constructor.

Here is my example. Can someone tell me if it's possible to run it?

```
public class AbstractClass {
    //this abstract class does not have a default constructor, nor its subclasses
    public AbstractClass(SomeClassName obj) {
        //use obj for initialization
    }
}

//this factory class should create objects of type T that inherit 
//from AbstractClass and invoke the non-default constructor
public class FactoryClass {
    public static T BuildObject<T> (SomeClassName obj) where T: AbstractClass {
        return new T(obj); //does not work?!?!?!
    }
}


//Edit: ANSWER!!!
public static T BuildObject<T>(SomeClassUsedForTheConstructor item) where T : SomeAbstractClass { 
return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), item); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class and GetConstructor.  Once you get the ConstructorInfo object, use the Invoke Method.

```
var x = typeof(T);
var t = x.GetConstructor(new[] {obj.GetType()});
object u = t.Invoke(<inputs>);
```

Comment: This is what I used to use, but now I use `Activator.CreateInstance` as mentioned by Brian.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))` in my generics that need to create new objects of type T.  It works really well.

Comment: This should go into the .net rocks podcast! thanks for the answer.

Comment: //final code
        public static T BuildObject<T>(SomeClassUsedForTheConstructor item) where T : SomeAbstractClass
        {
            return (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (T), item);
        }

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can instantiate generic types without [a default constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) on the constraint type.

Consider instead specifying an interface IAbstractClass, such that your factory class can set the SomeClassName parameter as a property of IAbstractClass.

Additionally, if a SomeClassName instance is required for initializing AbstractClass, consider also having an empty default constructor, but a rich initializer method defined in IAbstractClass.  For example:

```
public interface IAbstractClass { void Initialize(SomeClassName obj); }
```

That way, your static BuildObject method instead does:

```
public static T BuildObject<T>(SomeClassName obj) where T: AbstractClass 
{
  T newObject = new T();
  IAbstractClass ac = newObject as IAbstractClass;
  ac.Initialize(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, what you are trying to do is not possible using the built-in generic constraints alone. The *new* keyword only allows you to constrain the generic type to having a default constructor.

Comment: and only if T : new() is defined.